# Specflow - How to get Target Name from srprofile programatically in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, specflow, gherkin, specrun

Is there any way to get the Target name defined in specflow's srs profile ?

Below is what is defined in srs profile,

```
<Targets>
<Target name="Login">
      <Filter>@login</Filter>
</Target>
</Targets>
```

I want to get the name of the target "Login" and save it in a variable in C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't have an API to get the target name, but you can get to it with a little bit more stuff in the srProfile.

This is how you do it:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TestProfile xmlns="http://www.specflow.org/schemas/plus/TestProfile/1.5">
  <Targets>
    <Target name="Target1">
      <DeploymentTransformationSteps>
        <EnvironmentVariable variable="RUNNER_TARGET" value="Target1" />
      </DeploymentTransformationSteps>
    </Target>
    <Target name="Target2">
      <DeploymentTransformationSteps>
        <EnvironmentVariable variable="RUNNER_TARGET" value="Target2" />
      </DeploymentTransformationSteps>
    </Target>
  </Targets>
</TestProfile>
```

You specify a deployment transformation step which sets an environment variable to the name of the target.

In your bindings, you can get the value of the environment variable by normal .NET APIs.

```cs
var targetName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("RUNNER_TARGET");
```

You can find a complete example here: https://github.com/SpecFlowOSS/SpecFlow.Plus.Examples/tree/master/AccessTargetName

---

Full disclosure: I am one of the developers of SpecFlow and SpecFlow+